# Soundcard troubleshooting

Tags: audio, troubleshooting, sound-card, creative

My creative X fi xtreme audiois detected, without problems, drivers are up to date. But no sound is coming out.

The sound panel doesn't show the audio levels when I try something like youtube, and media players are not even playing the mp3s.

What can I check?

**UPDATE**

For more background.

I had just installed a new video  card, GeForce GTX 470 (I had the same model video card that got busted). I am not sure whether this is a coincidence or not.

I first had some issues where the sound was crashing (getting that repeated sound noise).

I then decided to format the pc and re-install windows (7 64-bit), as it needed one anyway. After the format I couldn't hear anything.

Drivers should be up to date.

Comment: Which OS do you have? Did it ever work fine? If yes, did this start happening after installing OS updates or changing OS settings?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Have you tried testing without the the video card?

Comment: Wish I could, don't have another to use. Will take the sound card to work tomorrow to try it out there.